# How to correctly use Material theme?

Tags: android, android-studio, material-design, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I'm developing an app with`minSdkVersion=21`. I don't wish to support older APIs below 21.

In `Project structure` > `Dependecies`, I can still see the `v7` support library attached. What is the reason behind this?

What is the correct way to apply `Material` theme to `API 21` devices because I keep on getting errors due to inflating of `Coordinator layout` or it tells me to use theme from `Theme.AppCompat` instead of `android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar`.

( some attributes skipped for beverity )

**Manifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    </activity>
</application>
```

**values\styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

**v21\styles.xml**

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <!-- item tags here -->
</style>
</resources>
```

**build.gradle**

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.karti.themetestv3"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Now, I'm getting 2 exceptions here :
1. `Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`
2. `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.`

I'd be pleased if someone could help. Thanks.

PS : MainActivity class extends `Activity` and not `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: Please paste your build.gradle file as well.

Comment: The AppCompat theme uses the Material theme on 21+ anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the reason behind this?

Because either you added it yourself or you used a template that added it. For example, the Android Studio new-project and new-activity wizard templates that ship with the IDE all use `appcompat-v7`.

> What is the correct way to apply Material theme to API 21 devices because I keep on getting errors due to inflating of Coordinator layout or it tells me to use theme from Theme.AppCompat instead of android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar.

You cannot use `CoordinatorLayout`, or anything from the Android Design Support library, unless you also use `appcompat-v7` and all that entails (e.g., changing your theme, using `AppCompatActivity`).

So, your choices are:

1. Avoid `appcompat-v7`, leave your activity and stuff alone, but then don't use `CoordinatorLayout`, or
2. Use `appcompat-v7`, or
3. Avoid `appcompat-v7`, leave your activity and stuff alone, and attempt to cross-port `CoordinatorLayout` and anything else that you want to use from the Android Design Support library to not use `appcompat-v7`

I haven't tried cross-porting `CoordinatorLayout`. Cross-porting `ActionBarDrawerToggle` went smoothly. Cross-porting `Snackbar` looked painful, so I use an open source one that is not tied to `appcompat-v7`.

Comment: Well, replacing `CoordinatorLayout` with other layouts like `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` solved the problem for now. I need to look up more on cross-porting as you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: @fireboy91: `CoordinatorLayout` is mostly for specialized scenarios where the contents need to react to events elsewhere, such as a FAB sliding up to make room for a `Snackbar`. Depending on the UI that you are creating, you may never need `CoordinatorLayout`.